# Elasticsearch "starts with" first word in phrases

Tags: elasticsearch, startswith

I try to implement an A - Z navigation for my content with Elasticsearch. 
What I need, is displaying all results which begins with e.g. a,b,c,... etc.

I've tried:

```
"query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix" : {
        "title" : {
            "query" : "a"
        }
      }
    }
```

The query mentioned above also display results, where within the string a word begins with a. 
Example:

"title": "Apfelpfannkuchen",

"title": "Affogato",

"title": "Kalbsschnitzel **a**n **A**ceto Balsamico",

I want to display only phrase where the FIRST word begins with a.

Here the mapping I use:

```
$params = array(
            'index' => 'my_index',
            'body' => array(
                'settings' => array(
                    'number_of_shards' => 1,
                    'index' => array(
                        'analysis' => array(
                            'filter' => array(
                                'nGram_filter' => array(
                                    'type' => 'nGram',
                                    'min_gram' => 2,
                                    'max_gram' => 20,
                                    'token_chars' => array('letter', 'digit', 'punctuation', 'symbol')
                                )
                            ),
                            'analyzer' => array(
                                'nGram_analyzer' => array(
                                    'type' => 'custom',
                                    'tokenizer' => 'whitespace',
                                    'filter' => array('lowercase', 'asciifolding', 'nGram_filter')
                                ),
                                'whitespace_analyzer' => array(
                                    'type' => 'custom',
                                    'tokenizer' => 'whitespace',
                                    'filter' => array('lowercase', 'asciifolding')
                                ),
                                'analyzer_startswith' => array(
                                    'tokenizer' => 'keyword',
                                    'filter' => 'lowercase'
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'mappings' => array(
                    'tags' => array(
                        '_all' => array(
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'index_analyzer' => 'nGram_analyzer',
                            'search_analyzer' => 'whitespace_analyzer'
                        ),
                        'properties' => array()

                    ),
                    'posts' => array(
                        '_all' => array(
                            'index_analyzer' => 'nGram_analyzer',
                            'search_analyzer' => 'whitespace_analyzer'
                        ),
                        'properties' => array(
                            'title' => array(
                                'type' => 'string',
                                'index_analyzer' => 'analyzer_startswith',
                                'search_analyzer' => 'analyzer_startswith'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Comment: Can you share mapping.

Comment: This looks like elasticsearch2, could you tag it as such ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using default mapping then it will not work for you.

You need to use [keyword tokenizer](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html) and [lowercase filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html) in mapping.

Mapping Will be :

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "analyzer_startswith": {
                        "tokenizer": "keyword",
                        "filter": "lowercase"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "test_index": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "search_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "index_analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Search query on `test_index` :

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "title": {
                "query": "a"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will return all post title starting with `a`

Comment: I ran into a problem: The query doesn't show more than 59 results.

Comment: I got it: I need to use "max_expansions". e.g.: "max_expansions": 1000

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this functionality without using `match_phrase_prefix` or `prefix`?

Comment: I'm dealing with structured logs across many applications. I can't declare all properties upfront, or know their types. Is there no way to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, can use `span_near`:

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "span_first": {
      "match": {
        "span_term": {
          "your_field": "first_token"
        }
      },
      "end": 1
    }
  },
  "_source": "your_field"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating @Roopendra 's answer according to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/polyfractal/4704772#gistcomment-1830051). Thus, there was an update and in recent versions `search` and `index` initializers seem not to work, there were replaced only to `initializers`, also `string` needs to be replaced to `text`.

Thus, we have the following **mapping file**:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "analyzer_startswith": {
                        "tokenizer": "keyword",
                        "filter": "lowercase"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "test_index": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_startswith",
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the following **query**:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "title": {
                "query": "a",
                "max_expansions": 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added `max_expansions` to the query because the default value seems to be `5` so I was getting erroneous results, in your case the value might be higher.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply using the field with .keyword or .raw suffixes.
For example to search for all the values starting with the letter 'a':

```
fieldName.keyword:a*
```

or

```
fieldName.raw:a*
```

[More info on keyword vs text fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845088/difference-between-keyword-and-text-in-elasticsearch#:%7E:text=The%20primary%20difference%20between%20the,fields%20are%20indexed%20as%20is.)