# Elasticsearch "LIKE prefix%" query without extra index field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I realized that querying Elasticsearch by

```
GET animals/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "Title": "ti"
        }
    }
}
```

returns

- **Tiger**
- **Timber** wolf
- **Tiger** snake
- Eye of a **tiger** *(that's unwanted)*

How can I achieve a real `match_phrase_prefix` and not a `match_token_prefix` without maintaining different `Title` fields just for applying different analyzers like described here:
[Elasticsearch "starts with" first word in phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741641/elasticsearch-starts-with-first-word-in-phrases#answer-29743407)

***---UPDATE 21.03.2017---***

I need the token based search as well as the "LIKE prefix%" search on the field `Title`!!! And I don't like to maintain an extra field per analyzer `Title_standard`, `Title_keyword` and `Title_xyz`. That would be a nightmare if all text properties of my model should be handled like this. Besides double data storage I have to retranslate all property names before I display the search hits to the customer!

---

(Elasticsearch 5 could be used)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it happen you need to amend your index-mapping to not split your tokens by whitespace and leave the string just 'as-is'. This is default behavior and this is how the `match_phrase_prefix` is actually working (on par with phrasal-spans, which are happening underneath).

- Update your mapping (important part is `"tokenizer" : "keyword"`):

  ```
  curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/my_animals -d '
  {
     "settings":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "my_analyzer":{
                 "type":"custom",
                 "tokenizer": "keyword",
                 "filter":[
                    "lowercase"
                 ]
              }
           }
        }
     },
    "mappings": {
      "animal": {
        "properties": {
          "Title": {
            "type":     "string",
            "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }'
  ```
- Afterwards you can use pure `prefix` query against your `Title` field:

  ```
  curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/my_animals/_search -d '
  {
      "query": {
          "prefix": {
              "Title": "ti"
          }
      }
  }'
  ```

Comment: Got `index_already_exists_exception`. Do you really mean "Update your mapping"? "Delete and recreate your index with this mapping" should be the correct advice.

Comment: Yep - you need to recreate your index from scratch - this is the simplest way :)