# Elasticsearch Array Intersect Query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to filter results based on whether an array field has at least
one element from another set.

I have a field containing an array of strings eg:

```
_source: {
...
keywords: [
"Data Science",
"Chemistry",
"Biology",
"Computer Science",
"Economics"
]
}
```

I'd like to filter the results such that keywords contain at least one of
a list of values, eg:

```
> ["History","Biology"] # would return the above document
> ["History","Geography"] # would not
```

It doesn't really matter how many it contains, just that it matches at
least one of them.

I tried the terms query, but that does not give me any results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) is an OR-query by default so the following will match

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "keywords": [
        "Chemistry",
        "Geography"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

if your condition `such that keywords contain at least one` is to be satisfied.

---

Now, if the requirement is to use an AND query (if one more more do **not** match, return null), you can use a bool-must query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "keywords": {
              "value": "Chemistry"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "keywords": {
              "value": "Geography"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Depending on the mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52845279/8160318) you may need to append `.keyword` to the field in question.

Comment: This helped, but it is also returning docs where keyword contains a substring of my keyword search term. Using your first example I am even getting docs which have "Organic Chemistry"

Comment: Could you please search your index mapping?