# String match in Elasticsearch API

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data that contains **email id's** of people, in the format of `firstname.lastname@example.com`, for example-

```
abc.def@example.com
stu.vwx@example
abd.rew@example.com
acw.try@example.com
swe.ewq@example.com
```

I want a query that gives me the first name results which I type in the search bar. For example,

**Input** -

```
a
```

**Result** -

```
abc
abd
acw
```

**Input**-

```
ab
```

**Result**-

```
abc
abd
```

Could someone please help me in how can I achieve this using the `Elasticsearch` query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elasticsearch "starts with" first word in phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741641/elasticsearch-starts-with-first-word-in-phrases)

Answer (score 0):

Regard to you index mapping if your email field is text type you can get desired result by this query

```html
GET /yourindexname/_search
{
  "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix" : {
        "email": {
            "query" : "a"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

As you may know we can get our index mapping by below api

```html
GET /yourindexname/_mapping
```